# Why does it gives error unreachable code in last statement print(second)

Tags: python, pycharm

```
first=[]

list_1=int(input("Enter the numbers of elements for 1st list = "))
for i in range(list_1):
    new = int(input())
    first.append(new)
    continue
print (first)


second=[]
list_2=int(input("Enter the number of elements in 2nd list= "))
for x in range(list_2):
    new_2=int(input())
    second.append(new_2)
    continue
    print(second)
```

Comment: Notice that `print(second)` is indented, making it part of the `for` loop. The `continue` stops execution of that block before the print. Just move it to the left.

Comment: And please mention what "it" is - and post the full error code.

Answer (score 1):

Python is a identation-sensitive language. In your code, `print(second)` is within the `for` loop but after the `continue` keyword.

Because `continue` is a flow control operation, it's essentially skipping `print(second)`, which is the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0):

Condition to continue is missing so complier found at compile time that last time is unreachable.

Parse 1 compilier
Parse 2 compiler

The continue statement breaks one iteration (in the loop), if a specified condition occurs, and continues with the next iteration in the loop.

This example skips the value of 4:

Example

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 if (i == 4) {
   continue;
  }
  System.out.println(i);
 }
```

Comment: This reply is misleading, the original question is related to Python and not Java.

Comment: @alex Concept is same buddy